# Where does "Life of Ichabod" come from?

Tags: life-of-ichabod

In a German anthology, there was once a manga called "Life of Ichabod". It's about the son (Ichabod) of a lesbian woman and a criminal old man (it seems they don't know each other => sperm donation).

After the boy cuts off his foreskin, he meets friends of his father in a hospital and helps them fleeing from the police. After that, he goes back home.

This is the story from the first chapters, but I can't find any information about the manga. Was it a German-only manga? Is there any place in the internet where I can find anything about the manga?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for the [イハーブの生活](http://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=31555) (*The Life of Ichabod*) manga by Shouji Hiroyuki. It's spans 3 volumes.

> (Ichabod) is the boy who was born by artificial insemination as a child of two women. Elly of the part of father disappears, and it is a family of mother and child with Mary of the part of mother. Ihabu is rebuked by Mary that "you were born as a man is our greatest failure." One day, he cuts off his penis, and he looks for real father registered with a sperm bank and goes for an odyssey.

It was originally published in Kodansha's *Afternoon* magazine